# Why my button and a tag do not work at all

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am having an issue with the button and a tag will act like a paragraph won't open nothing won't do nothing and I can't figure it out.

here is my html for the page with the problems (on my other sections work just fine only on this section won't work.

```css
.main-bonus {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.bonus-logo {
  width: 600px;
  padding: 25px;
}

.main-bonus-txt {
  color: var(--main-l);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 0px;
}

.top-mb {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.place-bonus {
  position: relative;
  color: var(--main);
  margin: 40px;
  border: 1px solid var(--light);
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 360px;
  background-color: black;
}

.place-bonus h3 {
  margin: 10px 0px;
}

.place-bonus-1 {
  position: relative;
  color: var(--main);
  margin: 50px;
  border: 1px solid var(--light);
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 80%;
}

.left-mb {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.first-place {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 164px;
  left: 520px;
  width: 100px;
}

.second-place {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 167px;
  left: 186px;
  width: 100px;
}

.third-place {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 167px;
  left: 186px;
  width: 100px;
}

.bonus-simplu {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
  color: var(--main);
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-bonus">
  <div class="main-bonus-txt">
    <h1>Joacă ACUM FĂRĂ DEPUNERE</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="top-mb">
    <div class="place-bonus-1">
      <img src="img/bonus/magicjackpot.png" alt="Magic Jackpot Logo" class="bonus-logo">
      <img src="img/bonus/Asset-1.png" alt="" class="first-place">
      <h3>400 rotiri Burning si Shining (*depunere minima)</h3>
      <form action="https://stackoverflow.com/">
        <button class="bonus-simplu">Înregistrează-te si ia bonusul</button>
      </form>
      <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Ia bonusul</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="left-mb">
    <div class="place-bonus">
      <img src="img/bonus/superbet.png" alt="Superbet Logo" class="bonus-logo">
      <img src="img/bonus/Asset-2.png" alt="" class="second-place">
      <h3>200 rotiri FARA DEPUNERE Shining Crown</h3>
      <form action="https://stackoverflow.com/">
        <button class="bonus-simplu">Înregistrează-te si ia bonusul</button>
      </form>
      <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Ia bonusul</a>
    </div>
    <div class="place-bonus">
      <img src="img/bonus/winner.png" alt="Winner Logo" class="bonus-logo">
      <img src="img/bonus/Asset-3.png" alt="" class="third-place">
      <h3>100 rotiri FARA DEPUNERE Shining Crown</h3>
      <button class="bonus-simplu">Înregistrează-te si ia bonusul</button>
    </div>
    <div class="place-bonus">
      <img src="img/bonus/maxbet.png" alt="Maxbet Logo" class="bonus-logo">
      <h3>350 rotiri FARA DEPUNERE la Shining Crown</h3>
      <button class="bonus-simplu">Înregistrează-te si ia bonusul</button>
    </div>
    <div class="place-bonus">
      <img src="img/bonus/luck.png" alt="Luck Casino Logo" class="bonus-logo">
      <h3>25 rotiri FARA DEPUNERE + bonus CASH FARA RULAJ</h3>
      <button class="bonus-simplu">Înregistrează-te si ia bonusul</button>
    </div>
    <div class="place-bonus">
      <img src="img/bonus/frankcasino.png" alt="Frank Casino Logo" class="bonus-logo">
      <h3>500 rotiri GRATIS la EGT (*depunere minima)</h3>
      <button class="bonus-simplu">Înregistrează-te si ia bonusul</button>
    </div>
    <div class="place-bonus">
      <img src="img/bonus/unibet2.png" alt="Unibet Logo" class="bonus-logo">
      <h3>333 rotiri GRATIS la EGT (*depunere minima)</h3>
      <button class="bonus-simplu">Înregistrează-te si ia bonusul</button>
    </div>
    <div class="place-bonus">
      <img src="img/bonus/las-vegas-1.png" alt="Las Vegas Logo" class="bonus-logo">
      <h3>200 rotiri FARA DEPUNERE SuperHot (FĂRĂ RULAJ)</h3>
      <button class="bonus-simplu">Înregistrează-te si ia bonusul</button>
    </div>
    <div class="place-bonus">
      <img src="img/bonus/vladcazino.png" alt="Vlad Casino Logo" class="bonus-logo">
      <h3>400 rotiri GRATIS la EGT (*depunere minima)</h3>
      <button class="bonus-simplu">Înregistrează-te si ia bonusul</button>
    </div>
    <div class="place-bonus">
      <img src="img/bonus/mrbit.png" alt="MrBit Casino Logo" class="bonus-logo">
      <h3>250 rotiri GRATIS la EGT (*depunere minima)</h3>
      <button class="bonus-simplu">Înregistrează-te si ia bonusul</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I did check to see if any images overlay the buttons or a tag, but no luck... I google it but still didn't find anything..

Comment: Could you please provide more info about issue? I don't really understand what you mean by "not work".

Comment: When I click on the button or a tag will not open nothing will not do nothing act like a paragraph.

Comment: Well, I am sorry, but it seems to me, that HTML elements are working as intented. I've copied code you provided to several sandboxes, and it's just working as it should be. First of all, the "button" element alone isn't doing much, for any action you need to wrap it with form el as you did in `200 rotiri FARA DEPUNERE Shining Crown` and `400 rotiri Burning si Shining (*depunere minima)`. However to "redirect" you need to specify method like `<form action="https://stackoverflow.com/" method="GET">`. Although I do not recommend this approach and would use properly styles "<a href="">"  el.

Comment: Your z-index is -1 which means the element is pushed behind the body which is why you can't click on it.  Try removing the z-index and it should work fine

Comment: Thank you Pete your solution work, I didn't knew the z-index will affect links as well, thank you again.